# pandas.series and line graph related question

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following series and i would like to plot this on a line graph with xaxis=releaseyear, yaxis=revenuemean, and index=genres

```
dfgroupbygenres    
release_year  genres         
1960          Action             5.981781e+07
              Adventure          7.232881e+06
              Comedy             4.432997e+07
              Crime              0.000000e+00
              Drama              6.975962e+07
                                 ...     
2015          Science Fiction    1.028802e+08
              TV Movie           0.000000e+00
              Thriller           4.166720e+07
              War                7.217865e+07
              Western            1.056374e+08
Name: revenue_adj, Length: 1064, dtype: float64
```

but when i do 
    lines = dfgroupbygenres.plot.line()
I get

[image: line chart]

How do i make this work to graph the data the right way?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the revenue mean of that year or of the year and genre?

Comment: i want to plot revenue for genres over years.

Comment: What is the name of the column with the means?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='release_year', y='revenue_adj', hue='genres', data=dfgroupbygenres)
```